# In a pandas dataframe, how do I get values satisfying a specific condition based upon checking against subsequent rows to a point?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, algorithmic-trading

I will try to explain the problem:
I have a dataframe df_resampled related to candlestick market data over which I am performing some analysis going through candle by candle (this is necessary for future reasons). It is datetime indexed, wiht the current_index available.

During this process, I populate a boolean column "Tsph"

Now during each candle I need to specifically extract all cases where "Tsph" is true in addition to:

- For each instance the "High" (another column) where "Tsph" is true, between that index and current index, this "High" value should be the highest (>=) all subsequent candles, otherwise it is to be ignored

In simpler terms I want to get all Tsph values such that the high of this value has not been crossed till the current index.

Some further considerations:

- Ideally I want this as efficient as possible, as there are equivalent variants for eg the "low value"

I can potentially loop over tsph_indices = df_resampled[df_resampled['Tsph']].index, but I am hoping for a better designed choice. I am open to reworking some things as needed, but it is small part of greater code, so I would prefer to stay within the decribed parameters.

- Example of my attempt:

```html
tsph_indices = df_resampled[df_resampled['Tsph']].index
tspl_indices = df_resampled[df_resampled['Tspl']].index
valid_tspl_indices = []
valid_tsph_indices = []
for tsph_index in tsph_indices:
    tsph_candle = df.loc[tsph_index]
    if tsph_candle["High"] == df.loc[minue_index_series.between(
        tsph_index, forming_index, inclusive='left')]['High'].max():
        valid_tsph.append(tsph_candle)
for tspl_index in tslh_indices:
    tspl_candle = df.loc[tspl_index]
    if tspl_candle["Low"] == df.loc[minue_index_series.between(
        tspl_index, forming_index, inclusive='left')]['Low'].min():
        valid_tspl.append(tspl_candle)
```

I will try to add a proper example once I find an appropriate one, but as for now lets say:
I have candles(rows) 1-20, where rows 3, 8, 11 and 12 are tsph:

- when on index 11, if say candle 10 goes higher than candle 8 but not 3, then 3 is the only valid tsph
- if on candle 14 where candle 12 has gone over 3 as well but not over 11 and has not been gone over itself, then 11 and 12 are only valid tsph

Comment: A minimal example of data, expected output is so much clearer than complex explanations.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put there **small** sample dataframe and expected output.